# What prefix should I use to address individuals younger that 18 yrs?

Tags: formality, prefixes

Many summer programs/university applications require me to provide a prefix I would prefer to be called by. I always type "Mr.", but as I'm younger than 18, is this appropriate usage? Should I just leave it blank? In other words, what's the correct prefix I should call people under the age of 18 by?

Comment: Good question. I think if you are 16 or older, Mr. and Ms. (for a young woman) is acceptable for filling a form. For a 12-year-old, calling them Mr. does sound severe and straitlaced.

Comment: "Mr." is not a prefix, it's called [an honorific (title)/address term](https://www.thoughtco.com/honorific-definition-and-examples-1690936).

Comment: If it's a university application, I'm guessing that you are old enough to be Mr. Younger boys used to be formally addressed as 'Master' - I see Oxford Dictionaries doesn't regard this usage as 'dated', but it's rarely used now.

Comment: @KateBunting At least informally (which doesn't help in terms of an application form), I've also heard *young* used. But I think it's most common these days to refer to children just by their first name, or without any honorific at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, it is, though I didn't go on to spell that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an application, it probably doesn't matter whether you chose blank or the title that fits you best ("Mr."). Probably the title would not find its way into anything besides perhaps automated paperwork. (In the unlikely case that people start addressing you with "Mr." and that makes you uncomfortable, you can just ask them to call you by your first name.)

Having gone to college not so long ago, I can say that people don't usually use a title for you even at that point:

- You address your fellow students by their first names (or a nickname). Some of these students are going to be older than you, but it works the same.
- Professors address you by your first name (or a nickname, depending on the professor).

(For the sake of completion, I'll note that some nicknames are just the person's last name, without a title.)

In fact, in college you're really only on the cusp of being able to refer to other, older adults without titles:

- You usually address professors as "Professor" plus their last name or the proper title (Dr./Mrs./Ms./Mr.) plus their last name. (For a foreign language class the professor may asked to be addressed in that foreign language, like "Señora Smith", even when you're speaking English.) There are some professors who will tell you you can address them by their first name (sometimes asking for that exclusively over the other forms).

If you're younger than this, school situations are pretty similar to this, except teachers are much less likely to let you address them by their first names.

Also, this is likely to vary by culture, so I'll note that this answer is based off my American perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally it was Master but this may be a bit old-fashioned now (in which case Mr seems ok).

Comment: Let's say that I have been acutely aware of conversations around me since the assassination of JFK , and I can say with absolute certainly that in the years since, I have never once heard of anyone outside of a historical novel or movie being referred to as "Master". Wait -- yes -- attorneys in France are referred to as _Maître_. But that, of course, is not English. _Mr._ is just fine.

Comment: @IsabelArcher See my comment above about the dictionary. In my youth, a letter to a boy might well have 'Master John Smith' on the envelope, but he would hardly ever be addressed that way in conversation.

Comment: @Kate Bunting All those years ago, I received a few such letters. I suspect from Isabel's comment that it might be British English rather than American English.